# How to use the 4-in-1 card reader on my Lenovo x100e?

Tags: sd-card, memory-card, card-reader, sdhc

My Lenovo x100e laptop has a "4-in-1" card reader that's supposed to handle SD/SDHC, MMC, Memory Stick and MS Pro, but I can't insert my SDHC card (a "SANDISK SECURE DIGITAL EXTREME SDHC 16GB 30MB/S"). It enters a bit and looks lite it will fit, but then it doesn't get any further in (and yes, I've tried to turn it around). It really doesn't move, and I'm afraid to break something if I push harder.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Yes, I really was missing something obvious: The card is not supposed to be inserted all the way, just halfway. So there really was no problem. And I'm supposed to be a highly qualified computer professional...

I got confused by every other card reader I've had, all of which you insert the card all the way in. I guess it's because this one is 4-in-1, and some card types are smaller, so the slot has to be more shallow.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve on a W500 with this solution for a T61:

http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-70881

The solution does not involve any drivers that were not already on the computer, so it doesn't appear to be version specific.